# SQLAlchemy Connections, pooling, and SQLite

Tags: sqlite, sqlalchemy

so, my design calls for a separate SQLite file for each "project".. I am reading through the SQLAlchemy Pooling docs more carefully.. my guess right now is that I dont want to fool with pooling at all, but this is really a separate connection engine for each project.. Agree??

In that case, when I create the engine, either I connect to a file named by convention, or create a new SQLite file and supply a schema template... ??

Answer (score 3):

Ehm, what? Connection Pools contain many connections to the same (database) server. It takes time to establish a new connection, so when there are *many short-lived processes*  using *the same* database, it's handy to have a pool of already established connections. The processes can check out a connection, do their thing and return it, without having wait while opening a new connection.

In any case, all connections go to the same database, given by the URI passed to `create_engine`

Answer (score 0):

First, some vocabulary. SQLAlchemy defines schemas with **MetaData** objects, containing objects representing tables and other database entities. Metadata objects can be *optionally* "bound" to **engines** that are what you think of as "pools."

To create a standard schema and use it across multiple databases, you'll want to create one **metadata** object and use it with several **engines**, each engine being a database you connect to. Here's an example, from the interactive iPython prompt. Note that each of these SQLite engines connect to different in-memory databases; connection1 and connection2 do not connect to the same database:

```
In [1]: from sqlalchemy import *
In [2]: metadata = MetaData()
In [3]: users_table = Table('users', metadata,
   ...:                     Column('id', Integer, primary_key=True),
   ...:                     Column('name', String))
In [4]: connection1 = create_engine('sqlite:///:memory:')
In [5]: connection2 = create_engine('sqlite:///:memory:')

In [6]: ## Create necessary tables
In [7]: metadata.create_all(bind=connection1)
In [8]: metadata.create_all(bind=connection2)

In [9]: ## Insert data
In [10]: connection1.execute(
             users_table.insert(values={'name': 'Mike'}, bind=connection1))
In [11]: connection2.execute(
             users_table.insert(values={'name': 'Jim'}, bind=connection2))

In [12]: print connection1.execute(users_table.select(bind=connection1)).fetchall()
[(1, u'Mike')]

In [13]: print connection2.execute(users_table.select(bind=connection2)).fetchall()
[(1, u'Jim')]
```

As you can see, I connect to two sqlite databases and executed statements on each using a common schema stored in my **metedata** object. If I were you, I'd start by just using the create_engine method and not worry about pooling. When it comes time to optimize, you can tweak how databases are connected to using arguments to create_engine.